# Pandas: changing cell value to np.nan changes from categorical data to float

Tags: python, pandas, series, categorical-data

I'm trying to convert some cells in a categorical column to NaN, but when I do it the column type changes to float. How can I keep the column as a categorical data?

Here is a working code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 2, 3, 2])
cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=[1, 2, 3], ordered=False)
s_cat = s.astype(cat_type)
s_cat
```

Gives:

```
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    2
dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1, 2, 3]
```

While:

```
def nanify(cell):
    if cell>2:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return int(cell)

s_cat.apply(nanify)
```

Results in the following:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
4    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you use a vectorial approach to change the data. Also to be able to compare the values, the categorical must be ordered:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 2, 3, 2])
cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=[1, 2, 3], ordered=True)
s_cat = s.astype(cat_type)

s_cat[s_cat>2] = pd.NA
```

output:

```
0      1
1      2
2      2
3    NaN
4      2
dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1 < 2 < 3]
```